# printf inside a loop doesnt seem to be printing any results

Tags: c, loops, printf

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to code a program that converts decimal into binary numbers. As far as I can see, the process of storying the digits into an array seems to be going smoothly, but I cant get them to print afterwards.
(note that using this method the number is first written backwards when converted, so you gotta invert it again at some point.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int num;
    int quo;
    int count;
    int count2;
    char aux;
    int pow2 = 1;
    int minus = 1;
    
    printf("Inform the positive whole number to be converted into binary: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    for (count = 0; num > pow2; ++count){ 
        pow2 = pow2 * 2;
    }

    char binary[count];

    printf("%d in binary is: ", num);

    for(count2 = 0; count2 < count; count2++) {
        binary[count2] = num % 2;
        quo = num / 2;
        num = quo;
    }

    while (minus <= count) {
        aux = binary[(count - minus)];
        putchar(aux);
        minus++;
    }
    putchar('\n');
    }
```

Comment: There's no `printf` inside a loop.

Answer (score 4):

The elements of `binary` are the numbers `0` and `1`. The argument to `putchar()` is a character code, so you're printing the codes `0` and `1`, not those characters. You can convert a number from `0` to `9` to the corresponding digit by adding it to the code for `0`.

```
    while (minus <= count) {
        aux = binary[(count - minus)];
        putchar('0' + aux);
        minus++;
    }
```

Or you could use `printf()`:

```
    while (minus <= count) {
        aux = binary[(count - minus)];
        printf("%d", aux);
        minus++;
    }
```